# Question related to mysql gem new method authentication

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I normally code on windows and using MYSQL4.1. And mysql gem version is 2.8.1. In my setup when I use mysql gem to access the MYSQL server, I give the root username and password of the sql server. And in rails db config file, I give user name as 'root' and its password and host as 'localhost'. My rails server and Mysql server are running on the same machine.

But recently I had to do a project in which I had to access the MYSQL server installed at a client site. It is a linux machine. I am not sure of the sql server's version number. To access it I was given a username and password for SSH and the root username and root password of the SQL server also. But for accessing that machine, in the mysql new method I have to specify the ssh login and user-password instead of sql user and password. 
I cant access the DB if I give the MySql root user and password. 
So, mysql.new(machine's public IP, ssh login id, ssh login password, db_name) works whereaes mysql.new(machine's public IP, 'root, root password, db_name) does not work. I am not sure, I understand what is happening. So, my question is can anyone explain this login behavior? Why cant I access the mysql server with the sql server's root login and root password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a little bit on what adamaig said:

When you're logged into the MySQL console as root, do this:

```
use mysql;
select User, Host from user;
```

MySQL should give you a table with the accounts and their respective hosts. You'll probably see that root can only log in from '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost'. You'll also probably see another account with credentials identical to those of the ssh account that was given to you.

Also, I would advise against giving root permission to log in from everywhere, it is a security risk.

But, if you ssh directly into the machine (using something like [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) if you're on Windows), you'll be able to log in as root from there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create a user in the remote db that allows remote login. The root account is typically not given permissions to login from '%' . Try looking at the mysql.user table to see what the permissions are. Then you might want to look at the mysql.com developer documents on setting up accounts and security. The answers there will be fuller than can be given here.